# Nucleo microcontroller board clock stability modifications

Tags: stm32, nucleo

I have an STM32 MCU board namely Nucleo-F303K8 and its schematics is given [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1956-stm32-nucleo32-boards-mb1180-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

For a better clock stability, I configured this board(by modifying some resistors as shown in the document) such that I can use the oscillator of the ST-link with the config in yellow:

[image]

So far so good. I also use UART1_TX and UART2_TX as follows:

[image]

I power this board from its USB. But now I want to power it from again USB port but not from a PC port but something like this [here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/usb-cables/1733530) which only provides power but no communication.

Would such replacement still let me to use the ST-link's oscillator?

Answer (score 0):

Try it. As long as the ST-LINK chip is up and running, it should start the crystal and output 8 MHz clock on MCO. It does not depend on the USB. If you have the tools you can measure the MCO before modding the board.